# Доступ к переменным из словаря словарей для реализации формулы

Tags: python, математика, словари, формулы

В общем, из интерфейса я получаю словарь словарей (`self.upd_tabdict`) по типу (цифры рандомные, не суть важно):

```
{'InputData_01': {'input_overall_01': 1.0,
              'input_overall_02': 2.0,
              'input_overall_03': 3.0,
              'input_overall_04': 4.0,
              'input_overall_05': 5.0,
              'input_overall_06': 6.0,
              'input_overall_07': 7.0,
              'input_overall_08': 8.0,
              'input_overall_09': 9.0,
              'input_overall_10': 10.0,
              'input_overall_11': 11.0,
              'input_overall_12': 12.0,
              'input_overall_13': 13.0},
'InputData_02': {'input_drilling_01': 25.0,
              'input_drilling_02': 23.0,
              'input_drilling_03': 10.0,
              'input_drilling_04': 5.0,
              'input_drilling_05': 4.5,
              'input_drilling_06': 7.4,
              'input_drilling_07': 1.0,
              'input_drilling_08': 9.0}}
```

Я хочу в другом классе реализовать расчётные формулы, соотвественно значения вложенного словаря являются исходными данными. Я подумал что лучше всего будет сделать это через 2 переменные следующим образом:

```
self.var = self.list(self.upd_tabdict[list(self.upd_tabdict.keys())[t]].values())[r]
```

где `t` это индекс ключей первого словоря, а `r` вложенного, из этого выражения мы получаем 1 переменную.

Вопрос: как лучше организовать задание переменных для формул в другом классе, чтобы не назначать каждую переменную вручную, а использовать только 2 индекса. Возможно через отдельный метод, который бы принимал `t,r` и вытаскивал переменную из словаря, дальше я пока не придумал.

Comment: что такое "индекс ключей словаря"?

Comment: выражение `self.list(self.upd_tabdict[list(self.upd_tabdict.keys())[0]].values())[1]` вернёт значение `2.0` Соотвественно `0` это индекс ключа первого словаря `InputData_01`, а `1` - индекс  значения вложенного словаря

Comment: Не смотря на то, что в последних версиях питона сохранность порядка элементов в словаре гарантируется, такого понятия как "индекс элемента словаря" не существует, то есть обращаться к элементу словаря по индексу - системно не верное решение. я бы на вашем месте заменил ключи на порядковые номера. Благо они в названиях ключей и так присутствуют.

Comment: То есть, ваша проблема сводится к подготовке данных. приведите словарь к виду `{1:{1:1, 2:2, 3:1000}, 2:{1:11, 2:22, 3:3000}`, и всё.

Comment: так я предварительно отсортировал словарь через `OrderedDict` чтобы быть увереным в правильности следования ключей, так что моя проблема скорее всего не в этом, но возможно вы правы. Я просто хотел придумать способ обращаться к этим значениям максимально удобным способом. Сейчас пробую реализовать метод, который делает это через 2 цифры, как и указал в вопросе